# javascript parse regex from json

Tags: javascript, regex

The desired regex value which I want to use is `/\S+\s*/g`.

I'm bringing it from json (by http call) so in json it stored like that: `{"delimiter": "S+s*"}`

When I'm trying to convert it with the bellow method:

```
var delim= new RegExp(delimiter,"g")
```

I'm getting the value `/S+s*/g` which is not same as the desired value.

I tried a lot of manipulations on the string itself, on the json and with the regex with no success to get the desired value

Can anybody help me to solve this issue

Comment: I'm confused - the string stored in JSON is not the desired regex. How should the RegExp creator know what you want if you feed it the wrong value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should store it like `{"delimiter": "\\S+\\s*"}`.

Check the code:

```
var data = {"delimiter": "\\S+\\s*"};
var delim= new RegExp(data.delimiter, "g");

console.log(delim);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!